# Java+Hibernate: HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class Servlet.MediiServletHibernate

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I have a webApp whitch shows a list of students and their marks. This list should can be exported using JasperReports. When the marks are showing on the desktop the application very well, but when I try to export the list I receive the following error:

```
type Exception report
message Error instantiating servlet class Servlet.MediiServletHibernate

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception 
javax.servlet.ServletException**: Error instantiating servlet class Servlet.MediiServletHibernate
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
root cause 

**java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:** Servlet.MediiServletHibernate
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.47 logs.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.47*
```

1.MediiServletHibernate

```
package Servlet;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JasperDesign;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader;
import net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer;
import Entities.Elev;

@WebServlet("/MediiServletsHibernate")

public class MediiServletHibernate extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 102831973239L;

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException,JRException {
    int id_cl = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id_cls"));
    List listElevi =new ArrayList();// DAO.EleviDAO.getEleviByClasa(id_cl);
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(
            "C:\\Users\\csuciu\\workspace1\\WebCatalog\\WebContent\\Reports\\Rep1.jrxml");

    JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanColDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(
            listElevi);

    Map parameters = new HashMap();
    parameters.put("id_clasa", id_cl);
    JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(inputStream);
    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager
            .compileReport(jasperDesign);
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,
            parameters, beanColDataSource);
    JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint);
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        processRequest(request, response);
    } catch (JRException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        processRequest(request, response);
    } catch (JRException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

2. web.xml

> ```
> <servlet>
>     <servlet-name>MediiServletsHibernate</servlet-name>
>     <servlet-class>Servlet.MediiServletHibernate</servlet-class>
>   </servlet>
> <servlet-mapping>
>     <servlet-name>ReportNoteServlets</servlet-name>
>     <url-pattern>/ReportNoteServlets</url-pattern>
>   </servlet-mapping>
> ```

3. jsp page

> ```
> <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
>   pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
> <html>
> <head>
> <%@page import="java.util.*, Entities.*, DAO.*, Servlet.*;"%>
> <%!String text1;
>   int id_elevi;
>   String numeElev;
>   int id_nota;%>
> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
> <title>Insert title here</title>
> </head>
>
> <body>
> <script>
>
> function Export1(id_cls){
>   url="MediiServletsHibernate";
>   window.location.href="http://localhost:8080/WebCatalog/"+url+"?id_clas="+id_cls;
> }
> </script>
>   <h1 align="center">Lista medii</h1>
>   <form action="Medii.jsp">
>       <fieldset
>           style="width: 230px; height: 70px; margin: auto; border: 2px solid">
>           <%
>               List<Clasa> lists = ClasaDAO.getClase();
>           %>
>           <p align="center"> <label> Select clasa </label> <select name="selected">
>
>               <%
>                   for (Clasa cl : lists) {
>               %>
>               <Option value="<%=cl.getId_clasa()%>"><%=cl.getNume_clasa()%></Option>
>               <%
>                   }
>               %>
>               </p>            
>               </select>
>               <p align="center">
>            <input type="submit" value=Submit></input>
>
>                   <input type="button" value="Export1"
>                   onclick="Export1(<%=request.getParameter("selected")%>)">
>               </p>
>
>       </fieldset>
>       <br>
>       <%
>           String id_clasa = request.getParameter("selected");
>           if (id_clasa != null) {
>               int id_clasa1 = Integer.parseInt(id_clasa);
>       %>
>
>
>       <table border="1" align="center">
>           <tr>
>               <th>Elev</th>
>               <th>Medie</th>
>           </tr>
>           <%
>               List<Elev> list = EleviDAO.getEleviByClasa(id_clasa1);
>
>                   for (Elev elv : list) {
>           %>
>           <tr>
>               <td><%=elv.getNume_elev()%></td>
>               <td><%=elv.getMedie()%></td>
>           </tr>
>           <%
>               }
>               }
>           %>
>
>       </table>
>   </form>
>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: check that your class is in WEB-INF/classes directory ... this should be WEB-INF/classes/Servlet/MediiServletHibernate.class

Note that package name should be all lower case in java.

Comment: Hello, My servlet package is not in WEB-INF directory, but I don't think that this is the problem, because my other servlets work fine.